# Make text box required depending on dropdown list value

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a dropdown list for the employees rank (e.g. Manager, Supervisor, Member, etc.) and a text box for Manager's/Supervisor's name. By default, the text box is not required so it could be empty.

However, if the dropdown list value is a "Member", then I need to make the text box required so empty value is not allowed.

I already have the requiredfieldvalidator in placed for the text box but I don't know how to disable/enable it depending on the value in dropdown list.

```
<ASP:DROPDOWNLIST id="drpLstEmRank" tabIndex="2" runat="server" WIDTH="321"></ASP:DROPDOWNLIST>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valDrpLstEmRank" runat="server" ControlToValidate="drpLstEmRank"
 Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"
 Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" InitialValue="(Select Rank)">Please select a rank</asp:RequiredFieldValidator></TD>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valTbHeadName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbHeadName"
 Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"
 Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt">Please input a head's name</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<ASP:TEXTBOX id="tbHeadName" runat="server" WIDTH="415" HEIGHT="26" MaxLength="50"></ASP:TEXTBOX>
```

Comment: U can make use of Jquery or javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can disable/enable the validator on the server side code in the Page_Load event as follows.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     valTbHeadName.Enabled = Request[drpLstEmRank.UniqueID] == "Member" ? true : false;
}
```

But dont forget to add the `AutoPostBack="true"` property to your dropdown list for the employees rank. Otherwise it wont work after changing the dropdownlist value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Client Side Solution

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("drpLstEmRank").change(function(){
      if(this.val() == "Member"){
       EnableValidator("#valTbHeadName");
      }
    else{
       DisableValidator("#valTbHeadName");
      }
    });
});

//Method to disable the validator
function DisableValidator(validatorId) {
    var validator = $(validatorId);
    ValidatorEnable(validator[0], false);
}

//Method to enable the validator
function EnableValidator(validatorId) {
    var validator = $(validatorId);
    ValidatorEnable(validator[0], true);
    validator.hide();   //hides the error message
}
```